# Javascript: Match a whole line containing comment characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I've a file like following

```
// Variables

// Greys
@linkColor:                 #000;

// Links
@linkColorHover:        darken(@linkColor, 15%);

// Fonts
@sansFontFamily:        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@altFontFamily:         @sansFontFamily;

// Size
@baseLineHeight:        20px;
```

I can read the file line-by-line. Is there any way to check a line, if it's not comment by regular expression.

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: Does not "slash slash anything" pattern meet your requirements? `/\/\/(.*)/`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your example also matches the blank lines. Can you please recommend a pattern, which will ensure that the matched lines starts with `@`, and contains one `:` and one `;`. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm reading the files by npm module `line-by-line`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Live example](http://regex101.com/r/kR0mO6/1)

This regular expression:

```
var isCommentLine = function (line) {
    var rex = /^\s*\/\/.*$|^\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*$/;
    return rex.test(line);
}
```

#### Will return

`true` for the following 4 lines:

```
// hello world
   // some comment
/* other comment */
   /* yet another one */
```

`false` for multiline comments

```
/* hello
 * thing
   bing
   world */
```

`false` for mixed code - comment lines:

```
color: red; // red color
```

So if your usecase is ok with this then you can use it